# What is going on inside this disc

Tags: magnetic-fields, metals, magnetic-moment

I recently saw a video of a copper disc repelling paper pins which I suppose are made up of steel. By watching the video carefully in slow motion, I feel there is something inside this copper disc (As the pins are getting rotated and thrown out from the disc's surface).

My questions are :

- What is going on here?
- How is this working?
- What could be inside this disc?
- As far as I know, there shouldn't be a ferromagnetic substance inside it, as paper pins are getting repelled.

I have uploaded the [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b638sP1t5kU).

Comment: There has to be a magnet inside the disc and the nails have been purposefully magnetised for this "trick".

Comment: If nails have purposefully magnetised, then they had sticked to the disc! Why they are repelling?

Comment: I don't know but a trick using magnetism is being used here.

Comment: I think, it's diamagnetic substance inside? Just a thought..

Comment: Not likely diamagnetic. Diamagnetism is a weak effect, so it's unlikely to be enough to do that to pins of that size. Could be any number of things: an electromagnet or a speaker, for instance.

Comment: A superconductor  inside the disk (well insulated) might be diamagnetic enough to repel magnetized bits of metal like that.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments suggested that the effect is caused by diamagnetism, other comments contained doubts, as diamagnetism is weak. Let me note, first, that copper is indeed diamagnetic (although it is not mentioned  in the video that the disk was made of copper, unless I missed something) and that effects of diamagnetism can be quite impressive (https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=copper+diamagnetic&&view=detail&mid=67B0211024968A13130367B0211024968A131303&&FORM=VDRVRV ). So the video in question could be made with diamagnetic copper and magnetized pins.